# Phantomjs stack error

Tags: selenium, java

```
    [ERROR - 2015-11-26T10:17:14.013Z] Session [9dd2e3a0-9426-11e5-986e-45afd4903e2f] - page.onError - msg: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'a.getElementById("ButtonID").addEventListener')

  :262 in error
[ERROR - 2015-11-26T10:17:14.016Z] Session [9dd2e3a0-9426-11e5-986e-45afd4903e2f] - page.onError - stack:
  (anonymous function) (http://c.supert.ag/digitouch-dijital-pazarlama/biletix/supertag-code-v30.js:9)
  fireTag (http://c.supert.ag/digitouch-dijital-pazarlama/biletix/supertag-code-v30.js:9)
  fireBaseContainer (http://c.supert.ag/digitouch-dijital-pazarlama/biletix/supertag-code-v30.js:9)
  t (http://c.supert.ag/digitouch-dijital-pazarlama/biletix/supertag-code-v30.js:9)
  (anonymous function) (http://c.supert.ag/digitouch-dijital-pazarlama/biletix/supertag-code-v30.js:9)

  :262 in error
```

I am visiting this page after clicking a region from right, for each event name there, in a while loop i go to that links and take event dates- hours from there.

http://www.biletix.com/search/TURKIYE/en#!date_sb:today

But it gave the error i wrote at the beginning, after 6. or 7. page. But despite that error, it can give what i want, name date and hour.

I use this at first page to wait to be clicked.(for clicking region):

```
new WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(
        ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"mpcat_zones\"]/div[2]/ul/li[2]/a"))).click();
```

After that, i use this to wait until loading the elements i wanted:

```
 new WebDriverWait(driver, 120).until(
            ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("all_result")));
```

That is driver. I did not define any options, capabilities:

```
file = new File("lib/phantomjs-2.0.0-windows/bin/phantomjs.exe");   
        System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", file.getAbsolutePath());
        driver = new PhantomJSDriver();
    driver.get(biletixURL);
```

The error occurs always at same place. Before giving output of that page

http://www.biletix.com/etkinlik/SSD50/TURKIYE/en

And sometimes, it gave error of `element not found, gave up. stop` And can not load or give output anything. But i created a explicit wait, i gave code of it.

And after explicit wait, i get the source.

Just executed and immediately it closed after that error:

```
    [ERROR - 2015-11-26T11:17:46.905Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand - Element(s) NOT Found: GAVE UP. Search Stop Time: 1448536666506

  :262 in error
[ERROR - 2015-11-26T11:17:48.241Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand - Element(s) NOT Found: GAVE UP. Search Stop Time: 1448536668217

  :262 in error
[ERROR - 2015-11-26T11:17:49.221Z] WebElementLocator - _handleLocateCommand - Element(s) NOT Found: GAVE UP. Search Stop Time: 1448536669166

  :262 in error
[ERROR - 2015-11-26T11:17:51.552Z] Session [5192ff30-942f-11e5-90e2-3ba3937b2cfc] - page.onError - msg: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'filterStartDate.toString')

  :262 in error
[ERROR - 2015-11-26T11:17:51.554Z] Session [5192ff30-942f-11e5-90e2-3ba3937b2cfc] - page.onError - stack:
  getDateIntervalFilter (http://www.biletix.com/scripts/search.js?v=:1033)
  initQuery (http://www.biletix.com/scripts/search.js?v=:571)
  doRegionFilter (http://www.biletix.com/scripts/search.js?v=:1049)
  dispatchEvent (:0)
  U (phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():119)
  $ (phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():108)
  $ (phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():101)
  gh (phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():141)
  sh (phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():152)
  (anonymous function) (phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():152)
  (anonymous function) (phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():152)
  (anonymous function) (phantomjs://webpage.evaluate():153)

  :262 in error
```

I am using Java and eclipse and Selenium. I dont understand why it cant load the page and cant find element sometimes, despite wait time.

Basic scenearia is:

1. Navigate to first page.
2. Click and choose a region with `phantomjs`
3. Get
   all page source and after regex pattern matching (to get names and
   urls), go that urls in a while loop of `match()`
4. At that page,
   get only hour (i already took name and date in previous page after
   clicked via `regex`)
5. Give output to console for each process in
   `while` loop.
6. `driver.close ()` or `driver.quit()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you use this dependency in your code?   I wonder if using this dependency might help?   Yes, use phantomjsdriver 1.2.1 with phantomjs binary 2.0.0.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.codeborne</groupId>
    <artifactId>phantomjsdriver</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1</version>
</dependency>
```